# Disable Mobile default keyboard to show up (Web APP, not APP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I have developed a JavaScript virtual keyboard and plan to not use the default mobile keyboard.

However, whenever I focus on the html textfield, textarea, or even use the div contenteditable="true">, the default keyboard pops out and covers my virtual keyboard.

Are there any ideas on how to disable or block the default mobile keyboard and prevent it from showing up?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problem and finally what I did was simply replace the `textarea` into a `div` element.

Added a click event to the div element (which was placed instead of the `textarea`) and when user clicks on the div element, the virtual keyboard div (keyboard is hidden inside a div when page loads) will be shown and when user types, content is appended [append and appendTo](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-append-and-appendto-example/) to the div.

Hope this will give you a brief idea on how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- Catch the onFocus event
- Set event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation();
- set the textarea.focus() into a setTimeout with 0ms delay.

  The focus() method in setTimeout will prevent the default system keyboard to be show.

(Verify the method names, I wrote it from scratch and sorry my English)